# Two questions about submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

I have two questions about submanifolds. For $k \geq 1$ one can define a $C^k$ submanifold $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ using equations: for $x \in M$ we say that $M$ is a $m$-submanifold at $x$ if there exist $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open and a $\varphi: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ which is a submersion at $x$, such that, say, $\varphi(x)=0$ and $U\cap M = \varphi^{-1}(\{0\})$. One can also use parametrizations: this time, one asks for a $\varphi : V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$, an immersion at $0$ (with $\varphi(0)=x$) and a homeomorphism onto $U\cap M$.

I have two questions about these equivalent definitions. Firstly regarding the use of the submersion hypothesis in giving $M$ a structure of a submanifold, I see that it is used both to guarantee that $M$ is a topological manifold and that it is smooth. But it feels to me like being a submersion is too strong a condition to ask on $\varphi$ for its level sets  to be non-degenerate. In algebraic geometry, let's say for a (irreducible) plane curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$ given by $f=0$, the underlying set is always a topological manifold and the submersion hypothesis, when verified, is only used to show it is smooth, and this feels more correct to me. This is due to $f$ being a polynomial, which is quite restrictive. This leads me to ask: in the absence of smooth structure, is there a way to put a general condition on $\varphi$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a topological manifold?

Secondly, for giving $M$ a manifold structure at $x$ using the second definition: if I'm not mistaken, one only needs that $\varphi$ be an immersion with image $U\cap M$, and open on its image. I don't need that it be injective. Am I wrong? Injectivity seems to be justified intuitively for preventing self-intersections, but all the self-intersections that I can image give parametrizations that are not open (the parametrizations of a plane curve with one loop that one imagines aren't open for instance). Maybe it is that all such maps (immersions from subsets of euclidean spaces, open on their image, etc.) are all injective?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes openness is "enough", but they're actually equivalent conditions here. Open immersions are automatically local diffeomorphisms (invariance of domain implies same dimension, so an immersion means in invertible derivative, so inverse function theorem guarantees local diffeomorphism).

Comment: @OsamaGhani The immersion isn't open, but open on its image, and I was asking for global injectivity, not local injectivity, which is a property of all immersions, regardless of openness and without invariance of domain.

Comment: There is a reason algebraic geometry is a separate discipline from differential geometry. In algebraic geomety a certain amount of "self-intersection" (e.g., x-shaped crossings) is allowed - necessary because this occurs in the level sets of polynomial equations being studied. In differential geometry, it is not allowed (with a limited exception for manifolds-with-boundary). A manifold should be homogenous - small neighborhoods of all points should look the same. The requirements you are asking about are there to enforce this homogeneity.